# How do I write a CRON expression to trigger a job every 90 seconds?

Tags: cron

I have scheduled a web job to run every minute using this "0 * * * * * CRON expression. It is running as expected. Then I changed the CRON expression from 0 * * * * * to */90 * * * * * to make it run every 90 seconds. But it is not running every 90 seconds.

How do I write a CRON expression for running a web job every 90 seconds?

Comment: 30 1 * * * * try this, Is this Working @Pradeep?

Comment: @RithwikBojja, I tried the above CRON expression. But the Job not running on every 90 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can split it into two seperate CRON expressions:

Running every three minutes on even minutes.

```
0 */3 * * * *
```

Running every three minutes on uneven minutes starting on the 30th second.

```
30 1-59/3 * * * *
```

Comment: I don't want to split into two separate CRON expressions. I want to use a single CRON expression for every 90 seconds.

Comment: @Pradeep It's not possible with a single expression.